# How to debug "File Not Found" for JSF

Tags: jsf

I am learning Java EE and JSF, and I often got an error message "404 - Not Found". How to debug this problem, and where to start?

Edited. It's not a FileNotFoundException error. Sorry. There is no exception thrown. It's an error message.

Comment: Basic HTTP response indicating that the address that you're requesting is invalid. Verify the page and the path you're requesting is valid

Answer (score 0):

place a Exception Breakpoint for FileNotFoundException

**For Eclipse:**

`Debug perspective->Breakpoints tab-> J! icon`